# exact way how final methods works in java

Tags: java, final

```
class Clidder {
    private final void flipper() {
        System.out.println("Clidder");
    }
}
public class Clidlet extends Clidder {
    public final void flipper() {
        System.out.println("Clidlet");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Clidlet().flipper();
    }
}
```

what is the result? to this question I expected the answer "compilation fails" because final method cannot be overridden and it does not allow inheritance. but the answer was "Cliddet" why is that? did I misunderstand something in this concept. how can this be the output? please explain.

Comment: Interesting edge case. Rule of thumb: just don't do that :)

Comment: if you really want to check final remove `private` keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The private modifier indicates that the method of flipper() in class of Clidder can not be seen from child class Clidlet. So it is not overriding but just looks like a new method declaration in the child class. Private method/field can not be override because it can not be seen.

Answer (score 1):

`private` methods are not overridden, so there is no override here, so no violation of `final`. In fact `final` on a `private` method is meaningless, or redundant, take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be "Cliddet" as your final method has `private` access modifier which makes it invisible for the child class. The flipper method in the `Clidlet` class effectively hiding the same method in the parent class. This is quite dangerous as a result will depend on whether it is invoked from the superclass or the subclass.

```
Clidlet  clidlet = new Clidlet();
clidlet.flipper(); // prints Clidlet

Clidder clidder = new Clidlet(); 
clidder.flipper(); // prints Clidder
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `private` keyword prevents subclass from accessing the method. As a result `Clidlet` asks `Clidder` about the method properties, receives response "I keep it private" and executes it's own method.

This case illustrate that the fact that `private` precedes (has higher priority than) `final`, that  `private final`== `private` and demonstrates the confusion it can lead to.

Comment: private + final is use less but it's legal? if there was no private keyword and only final then the answer is compilation fails, am I right?